# Unable to boot ubuntu 13.04 alongside windows 8

Tags: boot, uefi, boot-repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6036784
I used boot repair commands on try Ubuntu terminal. It said "EFI detected check options"

I used the recommended repair option. In the end it said "buggy kernel detected, do you want to activate (Windows efi files will be saved and renamed)?"

After the reboot, I didn't get the option to choose the OS. It justy goes straight to Windows 8.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Why did you use boot repair? Did you install Ubuntu?

Comment: Boot-Repair is needed to work around the grub2 os-prober bug. Or you can manually add boot stanzas. With UEFI you have to go into UEFI menu and choose ubuntu entry. And make ubuntu entry the default if that is what you want. Does your system boot Windows with secure boot off? Your Ubuntu does not have the secure boot version, but just the standard efi boot version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the log we see that you answered `No` to the question `Do you want to activate [Backup and rename Windows EFI files]?`.
Try again but this time answer `Yes`.

Comment: I followed the steps you said. I could get the grub and got ubuntu OS. But now am not able to go to windows 8. In the grub menu there is a option called windows 8 loader, wwhen i chose that it showed "error:can't find the command 'drivemap' error:Invalid EFI file path. Press any key to continue". When i press enter it'll again come to the grub menu. How to get both OS?

Comment: There should also be `Windows Boot UEFI loader` and `Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi` entries. Do they return the same error?

Comment: Yeah. Windows Boot UEFI loader option is working. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Some observations:

- Boot Repair seems to think that Secure Boot is disabled. (Line 556: `SecureBoot disabled.`) If this is inaccurate, it could be the cause of the problem. In this case, you could either use `efibootmgr` to add `EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` on the ESP to the boot list or (more easily) disable Secure Boot.
- Your `efibootmgr` output (on lines 1027-1038 and 1119-1130) shows GRUB configured to boot first, so GRUB *should* be the default boot manager. That is, there's nothing wrong with your configuration, assuming Secure Boot is disabled; if it's not working, it's most likely a firmware bug.

Some HPs are known to have a buggy EFI that ignores the boot order (as shown by `efibootmgr`). I recommend trying the following fixes/workarounds, in order:

1. Check with HP for a firmware update. After applying it, you might need to re-run Boot Repair.
2. Boot to Windows, open an Administrator Command Prompt window, and type `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`. (If you're booting with Secure Boot active, replace `grubx64.efi` with `shimx64.efi`.) This *might* overcome the problem. If it doesn't, try....
3. Run Boot Repair again, but select the advanced options and check the button to back up and replace the Windows boot loader file. (I don't recall the precise phrasing.) This option applies an ugly and hackish workaround for the EFI bug: It replaces the Windows boot loader with a copy of GRUB and reconfigures GRUB to use the backed-up Windows boot loader to boot Windows rather than use the original filename. This usually works, but Windows sometimes reverses the change; and it's confusing, since then GRUB is running from the filename usually reserved for the Windows boot loader.
4. Return the computer to the store from which you bought it for a refund, buy a new computer with a less-broken EFI, and write to HP to tell them why you returned their computer.

You might consider doing #4 earlier in the list. People seem oddly reluctant to take this action, but it's the only one that will get the attention of manufacturers who are shipping broken products. If solution #1 doesn't work, the computer is defective, so solutions #2 and #3 should be unnecessary, and a return of the product is justified.